# How to post an YouTube Video link through Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook

Specifically what I'm looking for is the embedded video player functionality you would receive if you had just manually shared a YouTube video but done programmatically through the Graph API.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you have to extract the URLs of the actual swf in the page and the thumbnail image yourself.

For example, this seems to work:

```
curl -F 'access_token=...' \
     -F 'message=Link to YouTube' \
     -F 'link=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3aICB2mUu2k' \
     -F 'source=http://www.youtube.com/v/3aICB2mUu2k' \
     -F 'picture=http://img.youtube.com/vi/3aICB2mUu2k/0.jpg' \
     https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed
```

See source: [Posting an embedded video link using the Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227607/posting-an-embedded-video-link-using-the-facebook-graph-api)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the old REST API or the new Graph API.  In either case you must have the  **publish_stream** permission.

If you want to use the Graph API you need to create a Post object and then post it to the graph feed url for that profile

> graph.facebook.com/PROFILE_ID/feed

You will want to set the **source** property in the Post object to the youTube url for the video.

**http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/**

If you want to use the older REST API the process is similar but you post to

> api-video.facebook.com/restserver.php

Answer (score -1):

Facebook does not allow youtube to play video on facebook anymore but direct them to youtube website to watch.