# share youtube videos from my website to news feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I am trying to build an application where I have youtube videos (each video has a unique url). I need to place share button below each video which can share the youtube video to facebook news feed from my website.

I tried to implement this but only URL is being shared. I wish that my application works in the way as youtube does. . When youtube video url's are copied and pasted in facebook wall, it generates a player with description. Also when youtube videos are shared directly from website, it does the same.

Please give me some suggestion in getting this work as per the above requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to look at this question: [Posting an embedded video link using the Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227607/posting-an-embedded-video-link-using-the-facebook-graph-api)

Comment: Thanks buddy.. I will check this and be back in a moment.. Thanks again. :)