# Posting an embedded YouTube link using the Facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, youtube

When you share a YouTube link on FB with intent it automatically embeds the YouTube player into your wall and it look like this

[image]

but... when I try to post the same video using [FB sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/), HelloFacebookSampleActivity => `postStatusUpdate()` mathood.

```
 public void postStatusUpdate() {
        if (user != null && hasPublishPermission()) {
            final String message ;

                message = ( user.getFirstName()+" "+ getString( R.string.status_update_link)+ " " +video_id + " " + getString(R.string.google_play_link));


            Request request = Request
                    .newStatusUpdateRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), message, new Request.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            showPublishResult(message, response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
                        }
                    });
            request.executeAsync();
        } else {
            pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE;
        }
    }
```

it look like this

[image]

so I find [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227607/posting-an-embedded-video-link-using-the-facebook-graph-api) that order to change the link format from `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<code>`  to  `http://www.youtube.com/e/<code>` or to add `&autoplay=1` after the `<code>`

but it doesnt work... I googled "facebook android embedded link youtube" but find nothing about this issue, need help

How I posting an embedded YouTube link (like pic 1 ) using the Facebook sdk ?

**UPDATE :**

I convert my code, now I'm using [Publish to Feed](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/publish-to-feed/) code. but the problem not solved

I try to [post](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) by source like facebook mansion , but it doesnt work...

```
  postParams.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
            postParams.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
            postParams.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
            postParams.putString("source","http://www.youtube.com/e/2raioEC7Hms");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved :  using tutorial [Publish to Feed](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/publish-to-feed/) , using [post](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)

```
 postParams.putString("message", "Link to YouTube");
        postParams.putString("link", "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3aICB2mUu2k");
        postParams.putString("source", "http://www.youtube.com/v/3aICB2mUu2k");
        postParams.putString("picture","http://img.youtube.com/vi/3aICB2mUu2k/0.jpg");
```

Comment: can u post the the detailed procedure.