# Posting an embedded Youtube video link using the Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, youtube

I want to post a Youtube video in my Facebook wall. I'm using Facebook Android SDK 3.0.1
I found this tutorial : 
[Posting an embedded YouTube link using the Facebook sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202305/posting-an-embedded-youtube-link-using-the-facebook-sdk)

When I post a Youtube video directly in my Facebook wall, it looks like this :

[image]

And when I post a Youtube video via my Android application, it look like this :

[image]

I have 2 issues in fact :

1) I don't want to show the **caption** (www.youtube.com)

2) When I click on the title, the video is played in the default browser or Chrome, why is it not just being played in Facebook wall ?

P.S : When I click on the picture on left, the video here is played in Facebook wall.

Here is how I tried:

```
Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
postParams.putString("message",  "message test");
postParams.putString("link", "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3aICB2mUu2k");
postParams.putString("source", "http://www.youtube.com/v/3aICB2mUu2k");
postParams.putString("picture", "http://img.youtube.com/vi/3aICB2mUu2k/0.jpg");
```

Comment: thats is preview .. u can make the custom preview and onclick of that open videp

Comment: Sorry, you didn't understand my two questions.

Comment: SocialService.subscribeApplicationInFB(this, message, link, source, pictureUrl, new FbPostingMessage() what is this for? er... I'm unable to get the code working here... Created a class urself or this i sfrom fb sdk 3.0.1?

Comment: I created the class yes. I edited my question