# Publishing links using Facebook graph API display feed as attachment on Facebook fan page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am try to publish link on Facebook fan page using graph API but it displayed as attachment not as normal feed which display thumbnail.
Where as when I try to publish same link on users wall it display properly showing image thumbnail.

Can any one tell me why Facebook graph API work differently.

Feed publish on FB fan page :

[image]

Feed on user wall :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all, I am finally able to solve this issue, the issue was I am using {page_id}/feed method to publish link for video and image, which displayed as attachment on Facebook fan page.

Solution : {page_id}/links with parameters [link, message, picture]

Answer (score 0):

Pls provide params you include in request to facebook. Maybe providing params as shown in answer to following question helps, i.e. picture?

[Posting an embedded video link using the Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227607/posting-an-embedded-video-link-using-the-facebook-graph-api)

Comment: I am using link and message parameters and try with Facebook explorer "https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/" for publishing links on Facebook fan page, above link is posting video on Facebook user wall which work fine for me as well but not on Facebook fan pages.